# grep exclude strings somthing with regular expression string

Tags: regex, linux, shell, grep

I had a test file:

```
base64_decode(xxx)
bas'.'e64'.'_decode(xxx)
ba'.'s'.'e64'.'_deco'.'de(xxx)
xxxxxxx
ttttttt
bbbbbb
vvvvvvv
b'.'a'.'s'.'e'.'64'.'_de'.'co'.'de(xxx)
```

I had the test command

```
grep -i -E -e "b[\'\.]*a[\'\.]*s[\'\.]*e[\'\.]*6[\'\.]*4[\'\.]*_[\'\.]*d[\'\.]*e[\'\.]*c[\'\.]*o[\'\.]*d[\'\.]*e[\'\.]*" test.txt
```

But,the result included the line

```
base64_decode(xxx)
```

I want remove this line:

```
base64_decode(xxx)
```

and must include this lines:

```
bas'.'e64'.'_decode(xxx)
ba'.'s'.'e64'.'_deco'.'de(xxx)
b'.'a'.'s'.'e'.'64'.'_de'.'co'.'de(xxx)
```

I think my regular expression string is wrong.

So help me please, thanks~~~

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can help us help you by formatting your code so we do not have to scroll it.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you want to do. Printing line numbers 1, 3, and 8 would produce your expected output but presumably that's not the solution you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know grep, so I'm not sure if this regex will work as it requires support for positive lookahead. But here it is:

```
^b(?=[ase64_dcod]*')[.']*a[.']*s[.']*e[.']*6[.']*4[.']*_[.']*d[.']*e[.']*c[.']*o[.']*d[.']*e[.']*.+$
```

Basically checks to see if there is a single quote somewhere after the initial 'b' before matching the rest of the string.

If supported, possessive modifiers (+) after the *'s might speed up searches.

https://regex101.com/r/UiCyCN/2

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "'" file
```

Output:

```
bas'.'e64'.'_decode(xxx)
ba'.'s'.'e64'.'_deco'.'de(xxx)
b'.'a'.'s'.'e'.'64'.'_de'.'co'.'de(xxx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you try this ?

```
cat <file> | grep -v  base64
```

Or as commented by Bohemian

```
grep -v base64 <file>
```

Comment: Or just `grep -v base64 <file>`